# Creating a Histogram from an Array using parallel Arraylists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, histogram

I writing a program learning arraylists. Essentially what it does is pulls from an array of Strings (each a word) and find the duplicates using to parallel arraylists. There are two arraylists one for the words and one for the number of times each word appears. The word in 0th spot of the words list corresponds to the number in the 0th spot of counts list and so on. I am successfully finding duplicate words and counting their occurrences but for words that occur only once I am getting a count of 2 and I can't seem to find out why. Here is the code

```
String[] wordList = fileContents.split("\\s");

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        words.add(wordList[0]);
        counts.add(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
            String tempWord = wordList[i];
            boolean foundEqual = false;
            int count = 0;
            for(int q = 0;q < words.size();q++) {
                if (tempWord.equals(words.get(q))) {
                    foundEqual = true;
                    counts.add(q, counts.get(q) + 1);
                } 

            }
            if(!foundEqual){
                words.add(tempWord);
                counts.add(1);
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(words.get(i) + ":" + counts.get(i));
        }
```

Here are the words

```
this is a test
this is also a test
this is the last test
```

And here it the output, as you can see the last three items should be 1 but are 2.

```
this:3
is:3
a:2
test:3
also:2
the:2
last:2
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking at the structure of `counts` and `words` in a debugger just before the print statement, it becomes clear that there is something amiss.

```
words:       counts
  0 = this     0 = 3
  1 = is       1 = 3
  2 = a        2 = 2
  3 = test     3 = 3
  4 = also     4 = 2
  5 = the      5 = 2
  6 = last     6 = 2
               7 = 1
               8 = 0
               9 = 1
              10 = 1
              11 = 1
              12 = 1
              13 = 1
              14 = 1
```

The problem is the add statement in the ArrayList.  From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29):

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
>   Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any
>   subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

And so, each time you are doing that `counts.add(q, counts.get(q) + 1)` you are inserting another element into the list.  You should instead use `set`.

Setting a breakpoint on the `for` and running this through a debugger ([eclipse debugging tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)) I can look at the arrays as each one of them grows:

```
words:       counts
  0 = this     0 = 0
```

This is from the first bit of:

```
    words.add(wordList[0]);
    counts.add(0);
```

When it hits the for loop again:

```
words:       counts
  0 = this     0 = 1
               1 = 0
```

What happened there is that the `counts.add(0,1)` put a 1 at the 0th location and then shifted everything else in the array down.

After several iterations of the not finding, we are back to this again.

```
words:       counts
  0 = this     0 = 1
  1 = is       1 = 0
  2 = a        2 = 1
  3 = test     3 = 1
               4 = 1
```

And then matching the 'this' again:

```
words:       counts
  0 = this     0 = 2
  1 = is       1 = 1
  2 = a        2 = 0
  3 = test     3 = 1
               4 = 1
               5 = 1
```

And you should be able to see how this structure is growing incorrectly.

Comment: As an aside, you *really* should use this code to investigate using an associative array (in Java called a Map) that will allow you to have a String => Integer relationship stored rather than a doubled ArrayList. It would be a good learning experience.

Comment: The solution above fixed it but I'm curious about yours. You said I am adding a new element into the list and thus bumping everything down but from what I understand in the newest version of java (or newer version) they changed it so that when you specify an index it only works on preexisting indexes. Maybe I'm not understanding what your saying. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Aside: your main loop should start at `i = 1`, since `i = 0` is covered before the loop starts.

The bug is that you're counting the first occurence on each subsequent trip through.  Change `q = 0` to `q = i + 1` to avoid that.

You'll also have to check your end conditions because of that.

Comment: Thanks so much! Slowly getting better at catching those little things!

Comment: There's more than one bug, since @MichaelT's point is also correct.  You have to `remove`, every time you `add`.